# Rspec fails when testing view edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, rspec

I'm working on my first rails app here and two of the generated tests don't pass:

```
Failures:

  1) gardens/edit renders the edit garden form
     Failure/Error: assert_select "inputgarden_name[name=?]", "garden[name]"

     Minitest::Assertion:
       Expected at least 1 element matching "inputgarden_name[name="garden[name]"]", found 0..
       Expected 0 to be >= 1.
     # ./spec/views/gardens/edit.html.haml_spec.rb:20:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/views/gardens/edit.html.haml_spec.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) gardens/new renders new garden form
     Failure/Error: assert_select "inputgarden_name[name=?]", "garden[name]"

     Minitest::Assertion:
       Expected at least 1 element matching "inputgarden_name[name="garden[name]"]", found 0..
       Expected 0 to be >= 1.
     # ./spec/views/gardens/new.html.haml_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/views/gardens/new.html.haml_spec.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.15 seconds (files took 2.74 seconds to load)
34 examples, 2 failures, 17 pending

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/views/gardens/edit.html.haml_spec.rb:15 # gardens/edit renders the edit garden form
rspec ./spec/views/gardens/new.html.haml_spec.rb:14 # gardens/new renders new garden form
```

I'm not sure why this is.  When I look at the test, I'm kind of surprised the path doesn't contain an id to edit (something like `/gardens/#{@garden.id}/edit`).  When I try to edit the test accordingly rspec fails to run telling me that `@garden` isn't instantiated yet.

*spec/views/gardens/edit.html.haml_spec.rb*:

```
  1 require 'rails_helper'
  2
  3
  4 RSpec.describe "gardens/edit", type: :view do
  5   before(:each) do
  6     @garden = assign(:garden, Garden.create!(
  7       :name => "MyString",
  8       :square_feet => 1,
  9       :zone => 1,
 10       :garden_type => "MyString",
 11       :user => nil
 12     ))
 13   end
 14
 15   it "renders the edit garden form" do
 16     render
 17
 18      assert_select "form[action=?][method=?]", garden_path(@garden), "post" do
 19 
 20        assert_select "input#garden_name[name=?]", "garden[name]"
 21 
 22        assert_select "input#garden_square_feet[name=?]", "garden[square_feet]"
 23 
 24        assert_select "input#garden_zone[name=?]", "garden[zone]"
 25 
 26        assert_select "input#garden_garden_type[name=?]", "garden[garden_type]"
 27 
 28        assert_select "input#garden_user_id[name=?]", "garden[user_id]"
 29      end
 30   end
 31 end
```

What do I have to do to make these tests pass?

**EDIT**: here's the edit views

*/app/views/gardens/edit.html.haml*:

```
%h1 Editing garden

= render 'form'

= link_to 'Show', @garden
\|
= link_to 'Back', gardens_path
```

*/app/views/gardens/_form.html.haml*:

```
= simple_form_for(@garden) do |f|
  = f.error_notification

  .form-inputs
    = f.input :name
    = f.input :square_feet
    = f.input :zone
    = f.input :garden_type
    = f.association :user

  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit
```

Comment: What does the view you're trying to spec look like? I'm not sure what you're saying about the path not containing an ID.

Comment: yes could you give some more info? What surprises me is that for the 2 different tests it gives the error at the same location (line 17 and 27). Could it be that  something goes wrong before your specific test between it ... end is run?

Comment: @Axe: Honestly, I'm pretty lost here; it's my first time with rspec and I'm just trying to figure out how to make these generated tests pass.  It's also my first rails app, so it is possible that I fell off that "Golden Path" somewhere without knowing it.  Also, I just updated my post and those line numbers have changed slightly (from an additional newline, I believe).

Comment: @DaveNewton: I'm not sure what these tests should look like.  I was expecting `RSpec.describe "gardens/edit"` to be more like `RSpec.describe "gardens/:id/edit"` or something.  I'm getting the impression that isn't necessary though.

Comment: What if you relax your selectors slightly? Does `assert_select "[name=?]", "garden[name]"` work for you?

Comment: Sorry if this is an obvious question, but did you check your HTML view for the correct ID and selector properties that you're testing?

Comment: It would probably be an obvious question for most folks, but in my case.. no.  From now on it will be obvious though, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message that you included indicates that an html element for the given matcher was not found.

For associations Simple Form gem generates `select` elements instead of `input` elements by default. https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations

You need to change the last assertion to:
`assert_select "select#garden_user_id[name=?]", "garden[user_id]"`

I am guessing the issue is occurring in the spec for the new view?

Comment: Well done; especially without even seeing the markup : )  Yeah, it was looking for an input field instead of a select field.  Thanks, a handful of things have just clicked into place for me.